# How to use getOffsetRange?

Tags: javascript, typescript, office-scripts

I have been trying to use `getOffsetRange` in office scripts but for the life of me I can't get it to work and I am getting errors stating `Property 'getOffsetRange' does not exist on type 'Worksheet'.`

I was thinking that perhaps due to this being a preview `getOffsetRange` may not be implemented yet however that doesn't really make sense since it is in the documentation

If anyone has any ideas how to get it to work or any help that would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pierre noted, the getOffsetRange() method isn't available on the worksheet object. To use getOffsetRange(), you can get range "A1" on the worksheet, and then get an offset from there:

```
// gets C3 range
let offsetRange = selectedSheet.getRange("A1").getOffsetRange(2,2);
```

Alternately, you can get a range by index on the worksheet object:

```
// gets C3 range
let worksheetOffsetRange = selectedSheet.getRangeByIndexes(2,2,1,1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation `getOffsetRange` is a method of the [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excel/excel.range#getoffsetrange-rowoffset--columnoffset-) class.

The error message you provided indicates you are calling the method on a [Worksheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excel/excel.worksheet) class instance.